# Auto Require in PHP

Tags: php, require, extends

aim: I wish to be able to extend any php class just using the extends statement and NO require statement like so:

```
<?php

    class some_child extends some_parent{

    }

?>
```

**BUT currently i have to do this:**

```
<?php

    require_once("some_parent.php");

    class some_child extends some_parent{

    }

?>
```

**Just to note:**

1. the parent class is NOT in the same folder as the child
2. the php.ini as been set correctly to include the path to the parent... so thats fine.

**QUESTION**
how do I achieve this, i.e. extending a parent class without requiring it?

apologies in advance if this is somewhat NOT constructive, i never know the rules here. TIA

**EDIT**

just to be a lil clearer, i'm looking for a "behind the scenes" solution, hoping i could set something in htaccess or php.ini to not only include the ncessary files, but also load them, to me it seems that include_path does not load the classes in that directory. which is why i'm getting fatal errors

lastly, i wouldnt pose this question if i hadnt seen it in action before. i know its possible, just looking for some guidance. thanks thanks

Comment: You need to use an autoloader http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Check for composer, `PSR-0 autoloading` and `classmaps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... yes, answering my own question... this meets my needs perfectly:

so I found out that you can set a php directive that will automatically prepend and\or append some php file to EVERY php file you access...

this is what i did:

in php.ini

auto_prepend_file = "require.php"

require.php contains all my require_once statements...

that meets my needs perfectly :) thanks for the previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest version I can show you:

```
function __autoload($className) { 
      if (file_exists($className . '.php')) { 
          require_once $className . '.php'; 
      } 
      return false; 
}
```

You will need to take into your account your directory structure to make sure your file loads correctly.

So if you have a directory called helpers and a directory called libraries it could look like this:

```
function __autoload($className) {

   $directories = array('helpers', 'libraries');

   foreach ($directories as $dir) {
      $path = '/'.$dir.'/'$className . '.php';
      if (file_exists($path)) { 
          require_once $path; 
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: so this would go in the child class yes? if so, im trying to eliminate the amount of code i add to the child class... reason being, if i have 50 children extending the same parent... im gonna have to do this autoload everytime.... im sure you can understand the redundancy. appreciate the answer though :)

Comment: No you just put this into its own file and include it at the top of your application. You only need to include this once.

Comment: thanks that is alot simpler :) however its not 100%, what interesting me is the comment on the OP, PSR-0... gonna have a look at that. thanks alot David

Comment: ok seems like my ventures have left me clueless... still... gonna give this method another shot and post back... thanks again

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do this I think is requiring all your files in your index and then running a core object.
Like this:

```
require_once ("config/config.php");
require_once ("config/application_config.php");
require_once ("config/database.php");

require_once ("system/systemcomponent.php");
require_once ("system/program.php");


$program = new Program ();
$program->run ();
```

And then you can make your Program object do whatever you want your program to do!
No worrying about requiring anything before extending.

UPDATE:

You could also do something like this.

```
//get all files in the root directory
$php_files = scandir ("./");

    //take out the "." and ".." directories (used for navigating)
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) 
        array_splice ($php_files, 0, 1);

    //Require all found files
    foreach ($php_files as $file)
        require_once ($file);
```

Be careful that it doesn't gulp up non .php files though.

Comment: Please take a look at `PHP autoload` http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: I was not aware of this function, thank you very much for notifying me.